# Regular conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ in Klenke's book

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

In his book "Probability theory", Klenke uses the following definition of transition kernel:

[image]

and if in $ii)$ the measure is a probability measure for all $\omega_1$ then $K$ is called a stochastic kernel.

Later on he defines regular conditional distribution of $Y$ given $\mathcal F$ as follows:

[image]

After the last line in the image above, he added "(the function from the factorization lemma with an arbitrary value for $x \notin X(\Omega)$) is called a regular conditional distribution of $Y$ given X.", which perplexes me a lot.

My attempt to understand this line:

First, I think he forgot to assume that the map $ \omega \mapsto K_{Y|\sigma(X)}(\omega, B)$ should be $\mathcal F$-measurable for any fixed $B \in \mathcal E$.

Next, I assume the previous statement holds and fix one $B \in \mathcal E$. Since $K_{Y|\sigma(X)}(\cdot, B)$ is a version of $ P(Y \in B | \sigma(X)) $ and is $\sigma(X)$-measurable too, by factorization theorem, there is a measurable function $\kappa(x, B)$ from $(E',\mathcal E')$ to $\mathbb R$ such that  $\kappa(X(\omega), B) =  K_{Y|\sigma(X)}(\omega, B) $ for all $\omega$. This shows, for every fixed $x \in X(\Omega))$, $B \mapsto \kappa(x,B)$ is a measure since it equals to $ K_{Y|\sigma(X)}(\omega_x, B) $ for any $B \in \mathcal E$ for some $\omega_x \in X^{-1}(x)$.

We still have to check if it is a measure for a fixed $x \notin X(\Omega)$. If I understand correctly his last line, we need to modify the map $x \mapsto \kappa(x,B)$ in the following way. Fix one probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal E$,  for any fixed $B$, define

$$ \forall x \in E', \qquad \kappa'(x,B) := \kappa(x,B) 1_{x \in X(\Omega)} + \mu(B)1_{x \notin X(\Omega)}. $$

Now we can easily check that for any fixed $x \in E'$, $B \mapsto \kappa'(x,B)$ is a probability measure. HOWEVER, measurability is now an issue! Unless $X(\Omega) \in \mathcal E'$, which rarely happens, then the map $x \mapsto \kappa'(x,B)$ is likely not $\mathcal E'$ measurable.

I think he missed this in this book. Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

My attempt to fix this issue: Suppose there is a set $N \in \mathcal E'$ such that $P^X(N)=1$ ($P^X$ is the distribution of $X$ on $(E',\mathcal E')$) and that $ N \subset X(\Omega)$ then we can define

$$ \forall x \in E', \qquad \kappa'(x,B) := \kappa(x,B) 1_{x \in N} + \mu(B)1_{x \notin N}. $$

The measurability is now resolved and it still holds that

\begin{align}
\int_{E} \kappa'(x,B) P^X(dx) &= \int_{N} \kappa(x,B) P^X(dx) \\\\
                &= \int_{E} \kappa(x,B) P^X(dx) \\\\
                &= \int_{\Omega} \kappa(X(\omega),B) P(d\omega) \\\\
                &= \int_{\Omega} K_{Y|\sigma(X)}(\omega,B) P(d\omega) \\\\
                &= \int_{\Omega} P(Y \in B | \sigma(X)) P(d\omega) \\\\
                &= P(Y \in B)
\end{align}
and so this new $\kappa'(\cdot,\cdot)$ is indeed a stochastic kernel from $(E',\mathcal E')$ to $(E, \mathcal E)$. However, I believe such a set $N$ does not always exists....

My question is: Is there a way to fix this issue? or is there other approach to this regular conditional distribution?

I borrow the images from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485548/regular-conditional-probability-of-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables-given-zero). And consulted several related questions such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485548/regular-conditional-probability-of-sum-of-bernoulli-random-variables-given-zero), or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118299/existence-of-regular-conditional-distribution-of-random-variable-given-the-value) (Fabio forgot the check measurability here!), and this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742468/motivation-for-regular-conditional-distribution-in-klenkes-book) too. However, they give no answers to my question.

Thank you for your suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 1):

I also think his construction of $\kappa_{Y,X}(x,A)$ is a bit strange.

Instead of making sense of the strange composition $\kappa_{Y,\sigma(X)}(X^{-1}(\omega),A)$, **I would declare** $\kappa_{Y,X}$ as the stochastic kernel from $(E', \mathcal{E}')$ to $(E, \mathcal{E})$ such that

$$ \int_{\Omega} \mathbf{1}_B(Y(\omega)) \mathbf{1}_A(X(\omega)) \, \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega)
= \int_{\mathcal{E}'} \kappa'_{Y,X}(x, B) \mathbf{1}_A(x) \, \mathbf{P}(X \in \mathrm{d}x) \tag{1}\label{e:def} $$

for all $A \in \mathcal{E}'$ and $B \in \mathcal{E}$, or equivalently,

$$ \mathbf{P}(Y \in B, X \in A)
= \int_{\mathcal{E}'} \mathbf{P}(Y \in B \mid X = x) \mathbf{1}_A(x) \, \mathbf{P}(X \in \mathrm{d}x) $$

where the notation $\kappa'_{Y,X}(x, B) = \mathbf{P}(Y \in B \mid X = x)$ is adopted for better readability and $\mathbf{P}(X \in \cdot) = (\mathbf{P}\circ X^{-1})(\cdot)$ is the distribution of $X$.

If the kernel $\kappa'_{Y,X}$ as defined above exists, then $\kappa_{Y,\sigma(X)}$ also exists and satisfies

$$ \kappa'_{Y,X}(X(\omega), B) = \kappa_{Y,\sigma(X)}(\omega, B) $$

holds for $\mathbf{P}$-a.e. $\omega$ for all $B \in \mathcal{E}$. Indeed, this follows from the change of variables formula applied to the right-hand side of $\eqref{e:def}$:

$$ \int_{\mathcal{E}'} \kappa'_{Y,X}(x, B) \mathbf{1}_A(x) \, \mathbf{P}(X \in \mathrm{d}x)
= \int_{\Omega} \kappa'_{Y,X}(X(\omega), B) \mathbf{1}_A(X(\omega)) \, \mathbf{P}(\mathrm{d}\omega). $$

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for passing by and dropping a comment. Shouldn't it be "I would declare $\kappa'_{Y|X}$...." because you use only $\kappa'$ after that? Also, if I understand correctly, you are not trying to construct $\kappa'_{X|Y}$ from $\kappa_{Y|\sigma(X)}$ but doing the reverse? Could you kindly explain more what you are trying to say :)? Thanks

Comment: @StrugglingScholar, Indeed my impression is that constructing $\kappa'_{Y|X}$ from $\kappa_{Y|\sigma(X)}$ seems causing a lot of troubles that are hard to mend. Instead, I am suggesting that it may be better to define $\kappa'_{Y|X}$ independently and relating this to $\kappa_{Y|\sigma(X)}$ if necessary.

Comment: Okey, I get it. I had a similar thought: we can define $ \kappa'_{Y|X}(\cdot,\cdot) $ to be an "almost stochastic kernel", i.e, $x \mapsto \kappa'_{Y|X}(x,B)$ is measurable for all $B$ (important for making sense of integration) and that $\kappa_{Y|X}(X(\omega),B) = \kappa_{Y|\sigma(X)} (\omega,B)$ for a.e. $\omega$. We can then define $P(Y\in B|X=x)$ to be $ \kappa'_{Y|X}(x,B)$ but it may happen that $P(Y\in B|X=x)$ may not be a probability measure for all $x \in E'$.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, in an attempt to find a rectification, I tumbled on the book "Conditional measures and applications" by M. M. Rao. It turns out that my approach to fix the problem with an $N \in E'$ such that $P(X\in N) = 1$ and $N \subset X(\Omega)$ is called perfectness (of the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal A)$) in the literature (which I know nothing about before). See page 133 of the book mentioned above.

Also the assumption $X(\Omega)$ is measurable turns out to be a crucial assumption in Doob's theorem too, see page 129 of the same book.

Conclusion: there is no way to fix the issue unless we make these assumptions!